# screenshots storage place back to desktop impossible

Tags: terminal, restore, screen-capture

I previously changed the settings of which folder to save screenshots.  Now I want to go back to the default settings, storing it on the desktop.  I have read what to do, in *Terminal* enter:`defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Desktop/` then `killall SystemUIServer`.

However, even after restarting the laptop, when I make a screenshot or a partial screenshot, I hear the sound of the shot but it doesn't appear on my desktop (or anywhere else).  How can I get the screenshots to appear in the default folder?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the command:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Desktop/
```

will set the default location for screenshots to be `/Desktop/`. What you actually want is to set it to be `/Users/yourusername/Desktop/`.

Try this, replacing `yourusername` with the username for your account:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Users/yourusername/Desktop/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it back to the default setting, then in a Terminal run the following commands:

```
defaults delete com.apple.screencapture location
killall SystemUIServer
```

The *default location* is the User's Desktop and does not require the `location` *key* to be set in the `com.apple.screencapture.plist` file, hence the `location` *key* is just deleted as it only exists when the *default* has been modified.

Then for the change to take effect, `killall SystemUIServer` does that.

Note: When a User Account is first created the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist` file does not exist and is only created if one modifies the *default* settings for screen captures.  As an example, changing the storage *location* of the screen shots, whether or not you want the *drop shadow* included and or the *file type*.

As an example I use the default *location* and *file type* but do not want the *drop shadow*, so the output of my `com.apple.screencapture.plist` file is:

```
$ defaults read com.apple.screencapture
{
    "disable-shadow" = 1;
}
```

If you do not have any setting changes other then the *storage location* and you want to truly revert to the default, then just delete the `.plist` file.

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist
killall SystemUIServer
```

These command can be combined on the command line by separating them with a semi-colon `;`.

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist ; killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: thanks for all the help, since both commentaries made sense, and I tried the both of them, something else seems the problem... I guess that although I hear the sound of the snap, there is actually no screenshot taken. I have had installed a new hard disk, and since it is practically empty I am quite sure now the screenshot is saved nowhere... if you have any advice on this, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Open the plist file in Xcode and remove the `location` key entirely. This can also be accomplished in Terminal with the command

`defaults delete com.apple.screencapture location; killall SystemUIServer`

Alternatively, you can just trash the plist file and make any needed modifications again.